# Use R to add a column to multiple dataframes using lapply

Tags: r, function, substring, lapply

I would like to add a column containing the year (found in the file name) to each column. I've spent several hours googling this, but can't get it to work. Am I making some simple error?

Conceptually, I'm making a list of the files, and then using lapply to calculate a column for each file in the list.

I'm using data from Census [OnTheMap.](https://onthemap.ces.census.gov/) Fresh download. All files are named thus: "points_2013" "points_2014" etc. Reading in the data using the following code:

```
library(maptools)
library(sp)
shps <- dir(getwd(), "*.shp")
for (shp in shps) assign(shp, readShapePoints(shp)) 
# the assign function will take the string representing shp
# and turn it into a variable which holds the spatial points data
```

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901597/lapply-to-add-columns-to-each-dataframe-in-a-list), except that I don't have a list of file names--I just want extract the entry in a column from the file name. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418574/how-to-add-a-column-to-a-dataframe-in-lapply) has a question, but no answers. [This person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418574/how-to-add-a-column-to-a-dataframe-in-lapply) tried to use [[ instead of $, with no luck. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653217/r-add-new-column-to-a-list-of-data-frames-with-lapply) seems to imply the fault may be in cbind vs. rbind..not sure. I'm not trying to output to csv, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382268/r-how-to-change-data-in-a-column-across-multiple-files-help-understanding-lapp) is not fully relevant.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343349/add-a-column-name-that-is-the-file-name-as-a-year-to-a-dataframe) is almost exactly what I am trying to do. Adapting the code from that example to my purpose yields the following:

```
dat <- ls(pattern="points_")
dat
ldf = lapply(dat, function(x) {
  # Add a column with the year
  dat$Year = substr(x,8,11)
  return(dat)
})
ldf
points_2014.shp$Year
```

But the last line still returns NULL!

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183680/r-function-loop-to-add-column-and-value-to-multiple-dataframes), I adapted their solution. Omitting the do.call and rbind, this seems to work:

```
lapply(points,
  function(x) {
    dat=get(x)
    dat$year = sub('.*_(.*)$','\\1',x)
    return(dat)
    })
points_2014.shp$year
```

But the last line returns a null.

Starting to wonder if there is something wrong with my R in some way. I tested it using [this example](https://www.r-bloggers.com/applying-same-changes-to-multiple-dataframes/), and it works, so the trouble is elsewhere.

```
# a dataframe
a <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 4:6)
a
# make a list of several dataframes, then apply function 
#(change column names, e.g.):
my.list <- list(a, a)
my.list <- lapply(my.list, function(x) {
  names(x) <- c("a", "b") 
  return(x)})
my.list
```

After some help from this site, my final code was:

```
#-------takes all the points files, adds the year, and then binds them together
points2<-do.call(rbind,lapply(ls(pattern='points_*'),
                              function(x) {
                                dat=get(x)
                                dat$year = substr(x,8,11)
                                dat
                              }))
points2$year
names(points2)
```

It does, however, use an rbind, which is helpful in the short term. In the long term, I will need to split it again, and use a cbind, so I can substract two columns from each other.

Comment: you're looping over parts of `dat` so you need to return the part and not the whole `dat`

Comment: Your last example also works. Take a look at `my.list` after you've run it - the `colnames` have changed.

Comment: Ok, excellent to know. In the last example, I'm looking at the wrong file: a vs my.list. I will edit it accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I had not designated anything to save what I was lapply'ing and cbind'ing. So it was running, but not modifying anything.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following Code:

```
for (i in names.of.objects){
  temp <- get(i)
  # do transformations on temp
  assign(i, temp)
}
```

This works, but is definitely not performant, since it does assignments of the whole data twice in a call by value manner.